# How to find source for win32 exception "error creating window handle"

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, window-handles

I'm looking for a little help regarding the win32 exception "error creating window handle".
From time to time our program (WinForms - C#) throws this exception and sometimes the windows even freeze, so that the users have to kick the process to be able to work again.

From the many other threads regarding this problem, I know what I should be looking for, but not extactly where as our program is quite big. So I was hoping that there might be a way to restrict the codelines I have to check... Are the any tools, which can help with this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short update: I solved the problem.

ProcDump didn't help me much, because I got pretty the same information from our logfiles. However, I was able to reproduce the error in our development environment. Thanks to debugger and displaying the user-objects count in the taskmanager I found the source of the memoryleak - an undisposed texbox which was created dynamically.

Thanks again for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

If this issue happens inside the debugger, you can set the debugger (I will assume Visual Studio as you're using C#?) to break on throwing an exception.  In your case you would want to set an exception breakpoint on (I think) `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception`.

Again assuming Visual Studio as your IDE, on the "Debug" menu is an "Exceptions..." item.  This allows you to tell the debugger to break when specific exceptions are a) thrown, or b) unhandled.

Under Common Language Runtime Exceptions, expand `System.ComponentModel`, and enable the checkbox in the Thrown column for `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception`.

Then just carry on as normal.  If during debugging the exception occurs, it should break into your program and allow you to see where it's happening.

**Edit**: If you can't reproduce the problem on your development machines, see if you're able to set up the target machine to produce a dump when a crash occurs.  One way of doing this is to run [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/dd996900).  Run it with the `-e` parameter to create a dump in the event of an exception.  Then you can analyse this back at the ranch.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and yes, I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

However, I haven't been able to reproduce the problem on our local machines yet and we don't have any administrator-rights on the users machines to install the studio there. 

But I will continue trying to reproduce the error - with the correctly configured debugger this time. Thanks for the reminder, I've totally forgotten about this option in all my (desperate) attempts to get to the source of this...

Comment: I've added some information which _may_ help, regarding creating a minidump which you can analyse at a later time.

Comment: The `-e` command line argument to ProcDump will write a minidump only in case of an unhandled exception. Given the nature of most C# code, an unhandled exception is rare. You may want to use `-e 1` instead to get a minidump on first-chance exceptions as well. Note that this will likely generate **lots** of minidumps.

Comment: @IInspectable: Ok, I didn't realise that, not being a C# person... but at least they're _mini_ dumps :)

Comment: Hi, thanks again. I'll give this ProcDump a try and see if I can get any useful information. May be a while though, till I can report back.